# Changing how android opens files so that it triggers a system service function

Tags: android, linux, java-native-interface, android-source

Where in AOSP code would I look to add code that triggers a custom system service whenever the user attempts to open a specifically named file?

For example, if a user opens a file on Microsoft Excel on Android, I'm assuming the application is creating a fileinputstream to read in the spreadsheet.

I followed the instructions on http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService

Comment: You might wish to explain exactly what you mean by "user attempts to open".

Comment: @CommonsWare Edited. Thanks

Comment: That does not explain, in technical terms let alone programming ones, what "user attempts to open" or "user opens a file" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm wondering if there is a system layer in Android that handles any kind of call made by the application layer to create a stream to read in the data from a file (FileInputStream, for example)

Answer (score 0):

All files open by any process are reflected in `/proc`. I would either modify the procfs to get immediate and full track of such events, or if the requirements allow, retreat to a less penetrating approach, monitoring `/proc` once in a short while.

See also *[How do I monitor opened files of a process in realtime?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58887/how-do-i-monitor-opened-files-of-a-process-in-realtime)*.

Comment: Is there a way to do this within the existing Java IO library by changing the FileInputStream source code?

Comment: Why? FileInputStream is not the single common point for all file access, even if you exclude non-Java usage.

Comment: Since the code I want to execute is already written in Java, I would much prefer if I could work with the existing Java library instead of going deeper. For Android applications written in Java, what would be the single common point for file access?

Comment: On Android, you have `libcore.io.IoBridge`, but this is an implementation detail that can change without notice on the next release. Actually, I am not sure if this goes back to 0.9.

Comment: No kernel modification is necessary - Linux already has inotify, which is exposed to Android Java code as FileObserver

Comment: @ChrisStratton: you are right, maybe you post this as answer?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Perfect. My only question is, what is the difference between FileObserver.OPEN and FileObserver.READ. Im assuming hat OPEN is triggered when a stream is created internally and READ is triggered when the data is read from the stream?